# How to limit Google Maps Places Autocomplete API results to cities?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I am building a weather app using openweather API and Google Maps autocomplete API with React. In order to limit suggestions to cities, based on the information I have reached on Google API documentation and this site, I wrote the code on index.html as follows:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?types=(cities)&key=${myApi}&libraries=places"></script>`

Also, added `types: ["(cities)"]`to the component that input window that uses autocomplete API. But neither of them worked and suggestions still include facility names and so on.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to put `types=(cities)` in your Maps JavaScript API script tag. Places APIs can work by [including](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries#:%7E:text=for%20more%20information.-,places,-enables%20your%20application) `libraries=places` alone.

You can use the  `types: ["(cities)"]` in your autocomplete options or or call setTypes() to  restrict predictions to certain place types.

```
const options = {
    types: ["(cities)"],
  };
```

Here's a [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/p5yod270/).